# Convert bytes[] to com.aspose.words.Document - Java API

Tags: java, spring, binary-data, aspose

I'm trying to make an endpoint in a Java API.
The call will need to pass a word file (which will be in bytes) for the endpoint. Then I need to translate these bytes into a com.aspose.words.Document so I apply `.getMailMerge().getFieldNames()` to it.

Basically I want to make an endpoint that will take in a word file that is in bytes[], and returns the fields in that word document.
I'm stuck on the part where I make the bytes into a file.

Here's what I have so far:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getFields", method = POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Fields getFieldsFromFile(@RequestBody byte[] file, @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String apiKey) {
        try {
            return myService.getFieldsFromFile(file, apiKey);
        } catch (Exception e) {
           ...handles error...
        }
    }
```

```
public Fields getFieldsFromFile(bytes[] file, String apiKey) throws ServiceException {

       {THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO MAKE THE FILE VAR, WHICH IS CURRENTLY BYTES,
                       INTO A DOCUMENT(COM.ASPOSE.WORDS.DOCUMENT)}

        try {
            return new Fields(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(file.getMailMerge().getFieldNames())).toArray(new String[0]));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...throws error...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your bytes are already in the good format, as i see in the documentation here https://apireference.aspose.com/words/java/com.aspose.words/Document

there is a constructor `Document(java.io.InputStreamstream)`

So you can use this :

```
public Fields getFieldsFromFile(bytes[] file, String apiKey) throws ServiceException {
        Document doc = new Document(new ByteArrayInputStream(file));
        try {
            return new Fields(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(file.getMailMerge().getFieldNames())).toArray(new String[0]));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...throws error...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yep, this is what I needed. TY